# Passing values to vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I can pass a value from a main  to my vue instance (another script) but won't work :(

```
<script>
let data = [{id:'1'}] //JUST SAMPLE

function pass_to_vue(data){
    return data
}
</script> 
 
<script>
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
    data: {
        external_value: pass_to_vue // HERE RECEIVE EXTERNAL VALUE
    }
})
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `pass_to_vue` is defined as a function. You need to call it. Also it returns whatever is passed to it. Not the `data` you defined.

Comment: To clarify what @OrkhanAlikhanov is saying, you need to have `function pass_to_vue() { return data }` and `external_value: pass_to_vue()` (although this is probably not the best solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at snippet below:

```js
let ext = [{id:'1'}] 
function pass_to_vue(data){
  return data
}
document.querySelector('#ext').innerText = JSON.stringify(ext)

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      external_value: '' 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.external_value = pass_to_vue(ext)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  vue value
  {{ external_value }}
  <p>change id</p>
  <input v-model="external_value[0].id" />
  <hr />
</div>
<p>external value</p>
<p id="ext"></p>
```